# How do auth tokens work

Tags: php, http, authentication, webserver, client-server

I am having trouble understanding auth tokens. The server generates a key for the user on successful login, then the user passes this up on every request to validate. Why is this secure? Couldn't the auth token be compromised while it is valid?

Comment: How can it be compromised? If the request is sent via https then you won`t worry about 'man in the middle' issue for instance

Comment: Then what's the advantage to always sending the password?

Comment: You send user/password then you get either a TOKEN or FALSE, then for each request you send the token to validate on the server side (you store in a table with an expiration time 2 days for example). When you receive the token you check if it is valid(EXISTS in the table) and if it is expired. Hope it was usefull

Comment: Okay yeah it is starting to make sense, is that the same table as the users or a separate one? Or does it not matter

Comment: Well you can store it in the same table, usually a user has one token and it`s expiration day (optional), or a separate table to keep track of his login then he would have multiple and you would query up the latest token